# iOS 10 Automatically join a WiFi using NEHotspotHelper

Tags: ios, nehotspothelper

It's possible to retrieve all SSIDs and network strengths using `NEHotspotHelper` related APIs. But does it allow apps to automatically join different WiFi networks based on application logic?

Comment: What does [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/Hotspot_Network_Subsystem_Guide/Contents/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016639) say?

Comment: @meaning-matters If I could find the answer there , I wouldn't post this question here. Documentation is unclear about it and I'm still waiting apple's approval for the entitlements to test this myself.

Comment: @Sleepwalkerfx, Have you got any success, I am able to search the nearby network and on its basis i fetched the desired wifi network (Using hard coded SSID in condition). All i can do here is to place password automatically and can also show a tag line below network in wifi setting page. Something like "Join 'xyz' to download content." a custom text. But user need to click on that network in order to connect. So if you have searched any method to connect automatically there. Please share it in reply. NOTE -  (NSHotSpotHelper entitlement enabled bundle ID required to fetch nearby wifi network.)

Comment: @RahulVerma what I found out was the same thing. We can not automate the joining part. Although we can omit the hassle of entering the password for the users, they still have to click on it.

Comment: @sleepwalkerfx Alright, And is there any method by which we can prioritise our desired network. Like if we again came back to range it ignore any other open network or connected one and just connect with desired network. I have played with NEHotspotHelperConfidence but no luck. Any suggestion?